# CSS - How do you create floating elements in columns?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a 3 column layout on my application where the items in the columns are all of equal width but varying height. I would like the items in the columns to take up all the available space per column. Image attached.

[image]

Any ideas on how to do this with CSS? Given a HTML layout like such:

```
<div className="container">
   <div className="item">
   <div className="item">
   <div className="item">
   <div className="item">
   <div className="item">
   <div className="item">
   ...
</div>
```

I was thinking of just working JSX in React to actually create 3 columns but I thought there might be a simple CSS way to do it.

Comment: can you please add css code also. thanks

Comment: That's what I'm asking about.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support? Seems like a good scenario for using css `flexbox`

Comment: flexbox is pretty well supported now so it should be fine. Im just not experienced enough with it to figure out a solution that easily

Comment: https://w3bits.com/labs/flexbox-masonry/2/  - You need 'VERTICAL MASONRY' from the link I guess.

Comment: That's exactly what I want ^

Comment: send me what you have tried. we cannot do everything for you

Comment: Thank you. Knowing the word for it really helps

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: JSX in React? I'm hearing *React* everywhere nowadays. That just sucks.

Comment: You might want to look for a library. Like https://github.com/shashankraider/react-bricks or https://github.com/paulcollett/react-masonry-css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @divy3993 for the link: https://w3bits.com/labs/flexbox-masonry/2/
It's a lot easier to google about this once you realize the coined term is 'Masonry'.

The parent container (`.container` in my example) has the styles:

```
.masonry { 
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  max-height: 800px;
  margin-left: -8px; /* Adjustment for the gutter */
  width: 100%;
}
```

The bricks should also have a little spacing (`.item` in my example):

```
.masonry-brick {
  margin: 0 8px 8px 0; /* Some gutter */
}
```

This solution is pretty limited as a `max-height` value is required as the items are essentially wrapping column to column. However, a simple-ish fix is to add javascript that calculates the height of the items. Various methods can be used to do this.